# Binance API place order

Tags: c#, api, timestamp, signature, binance

How do I place an order for futures? I am getting two errors: "The required timestamp parameter was not sent, was empty / null, or is not well formed." OR "The signature for this request is not valid."

```
public static async void Order()
    {
        string base_uri = "https://fapi.binance.com/fapi/v1/order?";
        string API_Key = "bSQQlu2k5tf0oSUGZsNGptisIxXLux8wb............................";
        string Secret_Key = "gWPKP66geFL0ryijnlU3TTepS61.............................";

        string symbol = "XRPUSDT";
        string side = "BUY";
        string type = "MARKET";
        string timeInForce = "GTC";

        decimal quantity = 20;
        long recvWindow = 5000;
        long timestamp = GetServerTime();

        string queryString = "symbol=" + symbol + "&side=" + side + "type=" + type + "&timeInForce=" + timeInForce;
        string signature = HMACHASH(queryString, Secret_Key);

        var Payload = new Credentials
        {
            Quantity = quantity,
            RecvWindow = recvWindow,
            Timestamp = timestamp,
            Signature = signature
        };

        var stringPayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Payload);
        var httpContent = new StringContent(stringPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        httpContent.Headers.Add("X-MBX-APIKEY", API_Key);

        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {

            var httpResponse = await httpClient.PostAsync(base_uri + queryString, httpContent);
            if (httpResponse.Content != null)
            {
                var responseContent = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(responseContent);
            }
        }

    }
```

This is how I get the timestamp

```
public static long GetServerTime()
    {
        string str = BinanceResponse("https://fapi.binance.com/fapi/v1/time");
        string[] arr = str.Split('\"');
        str = arr[2].Trim(':', '}');
        return long.Parse(str);
    }
```

Credentials class

```
internal class Credentials
{
    [JsonProperty("quantity")]
    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("recvWindow")]
    public long RecvWindow { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("timestamp")]
    public long Timestamp { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("signature")]
    public string Signature { get; set; }
}
```

After serialization

```
stringPayload = "{"quantity":20.0,"recvWindow":5000,"timestamp":1625061703897,"signature":"2794e66d4e5b5b6338782e058747a567db523.........................."}"
```

If I try like this:

```
string queryString = "symbol=" + symbol + "&side=" + side + "&type=" + type + 
            "&timeInForce=" + timeInForce + "&quantity=" + quantity + "&recvWindow=" + 
            recvWindow + "&timestamp=" + timestamp;

string signature = HMACHASH(queryString, Secret_Key);
queryString += "&signature=" + signature;
```

Error: "The signature for this request is not valid."

**Resolved!**
Thank you guys! I used Fiddler and found out that the "timeInForce" parameter is not needed for a type = "MARKET". All the problems were because of him.

```
string queryString = "symbol=" + symbol + "&side=" + side + "&type=" + type + 
             ̶"̶&̶t̶i̶m̶e̶I̶n̶F̶o̶r̶c̶e̶=̶"̶ ̶+̶ ̶t̶i̶m̶e̶I̶n̶F̶o̶r̶c̶e̶  + "&quantity=" + quantity + "&recvWindow=" + 
            recvWindow + "&timestamp=" + timestamp;
```

Comment: What does the `GetServerTime()` return? A `DateTime` object?

Comment: See proposal : https://docs.binance.org/list_instruction.html?force_isolation=true

Comment: GetServerTime() return long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response is in the error report. The Binance API require you to send an timestamp.

So you are probably not sending a correct timestamp or not correctly name it.

You can check your requests with an http sniffer like Fiddler.

It's possible that the API is case sensitive so, timestamp should not be "Timestamp" after the serialization. Check it

EDIT: Can you provide the documentation that you used to create the request ? Because the official binance API is asking for POST parameters only

Comment: Official binance API: "queryString: symbol=BTCUSDT&side=BUY&type=LIMIT&timeInForce=GTC
requestBody: quantity=1&price=9000&recvWindow=5000&timestamp= 1591702613943".

Comment: its not working. help
timestamp must be in url
Url: https://api.binance.com/api/v3/order/test?symbol=BTCUSDT&side=SELL&type=LIMIT&timestamp=1703261086403&signature=0c1a1c4534656a6114fa552eb537b2563fa057810de4........
Result: {"code":-1104,"msg":"Not all sent parameters were read; read '5' parameter(s) but was sent '6'."}

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend the Binance Postman collection on GitHub to see how to structure your requests:
[Binance Postman Collection](https://github.com/binance/binance-api-postman/)

Following this I also recommend the Binance Signature Examples found here: [Binance Signature Examples](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-signature-examples)

It looks like your signature is being generated **without** including all of the parameters of the request.

Binance supports setting your parameters for a post request either in the body or in the URL. Personally I've only used everything in the URL, but the signature has to verify all of the parameters, whereas your queryString variable is being converted into a signature, but other data is being sent in the payload afterwards and is not included in the signature.

Comment: "..parameters in the URL which I can see you are not doing". I did. I'm getting error: "The signature for this request is not valid." I can't find example request on c#. Python and Java only.

Comment: string queryString = "symbol=" + symbol + "&side=" + side + "type=" + type + "&timeInForce=" + timeInForce;

You don't append the timestamp or signature to this queryString in your example.

Comment: I did that. Then I get the error: "The signature for this request is not valid."

Comment: @ИвановИван I've edited my answer, your signature upon re-checking only covers some of the parameters being sent and your signature needs to cover all of the parameters.

Comment: This link you gave worked for me https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-signature-examples